# How do I convert varchar(20) in SQL Server to datetime in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm storing dates in SQL Server as `varchar` so they become strings in C# by Entity Framework.

Then I tried to convert then to date but the code throws an exception.

In SQL Server:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Achievements]
(
      ...   
      [DatePerformance] [VARCHAR](20) NULL, 
)
```

The date is stored in this format : "25/04/2019"

In C#:

```
public static School_LPEntities db = new School_LPEntities();
```

I tried:

```
List<Achievements> res = db.Achievements.Where(x =>  DateTime.Parse(x.DatePerformance) <= DateTime.Today.Date).ToList();
```

and:

```
List<Achievements> res = db.Achievements.Where(x =>   DateTime.ParseExact(x.DatePerformance, "dd/MM/yyyy",
 CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) <= DateTime.Today.Date).ToList();
```

The code throws:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime Parse(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store dates in a database as strings.  Store them using that secret and hard-to-guess type `date`.

Comment: Seconded. These [temporal] data types exist for many reasons, among which is that they prevent exactly the problem you're dealing with now: significance of representation in a data type that has no natural representation (ISO-8601 is a standard representation, but still arbitrary compared to its numeric value).

Comment: Storing dates as strings creates many kinds of problems, such as internationalization problems, sorting problems, and of course this problem you're dealing with.  Store them as date's, and it will save you many headaches.

Comment: You can't search for date ranges with that string format and there's no way to ensure all strings have the same format. A `date` value on the other hand is a binary value that takes just 3 bytes, sorting works as expected, indexing is easy and there's no way to insert invalid dates. There's no reason to store dates as strings.

Comment: In SQL Server you can use try_convert().  If the conversion fails, it will return a NULL rather than throwing an error.   For Example ...  Select try_convert(date,'25/04/2019',103)  ...

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in the comments, the number of good reasons to store your dates as varchar's in SQL is zero.

You said:

> so they become strings in C# by Entity Framework

Once you get the date in C# you can do this easily anyway with a `.ToString()`.

But... as to your specific error, what it's telling you is that you can't use this method inside of an Entity Framework LINQ statement.  It's best to think of LINQ statements as queries. Because, in fact, it needs to be able to convert your LINQ statement into an actual SQL query. You can't use `DateTime.Parse()` inside of a SQL query, so it throws this error.

If you really MUST store your dates as varchar's in the database (and again, this is a terrible idea) then I'm not seeing a really simple solution. Off hand, I would tell you to first, create your list, then loop through it:

```
List<Achievements> res = db.Achievements.ToList();
```

Then:

```
foreach (var achievement in res)
{
   if (DateTime.Parse(achievement.DatePerformance)  <= DateTime.Today.Date)
   {
       // do something here
   }
}
```

But this is a really clunky way to work around the real solution: Just store your dates as dates!!!